# What is the opposite of "in name only"?

Tags: phrases, antonyms

I want to describe a player who is not officially the captain of a team but shoulders as much responsibility. I have read the phrase *in name only* being used when a person holds a title, but doesn't perform or is unable to perform the duties typically associated with it. I would guess that in my case I am looking for a phrase which is opposite of *in name only*. The person is performing the duties but doesn't officially hold the title.

I searched for the opposite on Google but couldn't find one. Ended up with a similar result from a couple of dictionary searches as well.

Comment: You want ***de facto***.

Comment: `         :  .`

Comment: @DanBron That would be a good answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The person is performing the duties but doesn't officially hold the
>   title.

Jerry is the CEO in name only.

Csarina is *[effectively](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/effectively)* the CEO:

> 1.1 Actually but not officially or explicitly:
>
> *ODO*

Answer (score 8):

I think Scot's answer is perhaps more accurate, but for my exact sentence I ended up using:

> in all but name

It applies to conditions as well and is not limited to describing a person. Source: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+all+but+name

Comment: I consider that an excellent choice, @Shashank. *In **all but** name* is the opposite of  *in name **only***.